# Python Networking Using Pickle -- How to deal with incomplete data being sent?

Tags: python, networking, pickle

```py
def ReadData(self):
        data = ''
        try:
            data = self.c.recv(12000)
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)
        try:
            result = pickle.loads(data)
            return result
        except error as e:
            print(e)
```

```py
def SendData(self, addr, data):
        sData = pickle.dumps(data)
        addr.sendall(sData)
```

Currently the code above is what is being used, pretty simple to just send and read data (SendData in server, readdata in client); however, I am running into issues where there is incomplete data (i assume) and it is being sent over the network
the specific error is invalid unpickle key '\x14' (I am using the exact same version of Python on both systems so it does not have to do with that) or something like that which I can only assume is the result of incomplete data being sent over.  I am not sure about the correct way of going about this; perhaps using some separator and checking for that

Comment: Calculate a hash value of the pickle file and send it along with the file. If the received pickle doesn't match the origin hash value, throw an error.

Comment: Also, the example code has issues. For example here: `except socket.error as e: print(error)` the variable `error` is not defined and will probably throw an `UnboundLocalError`.  I think you meant `print(e)`.

Comment: Thats my bad I just fixed that in an edit. Thank you also I will try that